# How do I get a specific element while paring XML?

Tags: ios, xml, swift, parsing

I would just like to get "first subitem" from the XML document. So far everything works but it always seems to store the last subItem. Basically the program is reading straight through the XML doc and stopping once it finds what I want. Maybe I am not clear on how to stop the parsing after it has found the first item. Do I need to tell the program to stop after it finds the the first item or add them to an array and then pick out a specific part? Any help would be great.

XML Doc

```
<file>main file
     <item>
           <subItem>first subitem</subItem>
     </item>
 </file>
 <file>main file
     <item>
           <subItem>second subitem</subItem>
     </item>
 </file>
 <file>main file
     <item>
           <subItem>third subitem</subItem>
     </item>
 </file>
```

Swift file

```
class parseThis {

 var strXMLData:String = ""
 var currentElement:String = ""
 var passData:Bool=false
 var passName:Bool=false
 var itemNeeded = ""

// set up for parsing 

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String,
namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, 
attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

currentElement=elementName;
    if(elementName=="file" || elementName=="item" ||
  elementName=="subItem")

   {
        if(elementName=="subItem"){


        passName=false;
        }
        passData=true;
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String,
namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    currentElement="";
currentElement=elementName;
    if(elementName=="file" || elementName=="item" ||
  elementName=="subItem"){

     if(elementName=="subItem"){
      passName=false;
        }
        passData=false;
    }

}
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    if(passName){
        strXMLData=strXMLData+"\n\n"+string
    }

    if(passData)
    {

    itemNeeded = string



}
```

Answer (score 0):

A super simplistic way of looking at this is that you only need the `didFindCharacters` and `didEndElement`.  Every time you get into `didFindCharacters` you save them to a variable.  Then every time you end an element you check whether this is the correct element name and whether it's the first of that element name type.  Something like this:

```
var resultString : String?
var finalResultObject : String?

public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
}

public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCDATA CDATABlock: NSData)
{
    resultString = String(data: CDATABlock, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}

public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
{
    if(resultString == nil)
    {
        resultString = ""
    }
    resultString! += string
}

public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
{
    if(elementName == "subItem" && finalResultObject == nil)
    {
        //This is your first element of this type, save whatever you want.
        finalResultObject = resultString
    }
    resultString = nil
}

public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError)
{
    //Log something in debug if you would like to.
}
```